# Display information read from XML of a Geolocation API

Tags: xml, vb.net

This is my code so far. I'm having trouble with the line `Dim ip As String = wxe.<Response>.<ip>`. It won't display anything when I run the program and input an IP address.

Here's an image of the exception that is thrown when the program is run:

[image]

And here is an image of the XML file from a URL that the program is supposed to pull information from. Any advice on how to fix this problem and to better word this question is welcomed.

[image]

Disclaimer - The IP address used in the image is not my own. It is a random IP address that I thought of. It is no one in particular.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ipAddress As String = txtIP.Text.Trim()
        'If IsNumeric(ipAddress) Then
        'Dim txtIP As String = Shell("cmd /c nslookup" & lblStatus.Text)
        Dim url As String = "http://freegeoip.net/xml/" & ipAddress
        Dim wxe As XElement = XElement.Load(url)
        Dim ip As String = wxe.<Response>.<ip>
        'lblStatus.Text = txtIP
        lblStatus.Text = ip
        'End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should spend some time researching the various ways to work with XML

Comment: Add a `.Value` to the end of it.  e.g. `Dim ip As String = wxe.<Response>.<ip>.Value`  You'd do well to turn `Option Strict On`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ya. That is what I was doing. I would have a .@value, and it would never return anything.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. Your suggestion worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim ipAddress As String = txtIP.Text.Trim()
        lblStatus.Text = GetGeoData(ipAddress).CountryName

    End Sub

    Public Function GetGeoData(ByVal ipAddress As String) As Response

        Dim string_writer As New StringWriter()


        Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(String.Format("https://freegeoip.net/xml/{0}", ipAddress)), HttpWebRequest)
        Try
            Dim response = request.GetResponse
            Dim responseStream = response.GetResponseStream
            Dim reader = New StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8)

            Dim ms As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Response))

            Dim xmlReader As XmlReader = _
                xmlReader.Create(New System.IO.StringReader(reader.ReadToEnd))
            Dim r = CType(ms.Deserialize(xmlReader), Response)

            Return r
        Catch ex As WebException
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function
End Class
Public Class Response
    Public Property IP As String
    Public Property CountryCode As String
    Public Property CountryName As String
    Public Property RegionCode As String
    Public Property RegionName As String
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property ZipCode As String
    Public Property Latitude As String
    Public Property Longitude As String
    Public Property MetroCode As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(URL)

        Dim results = doc.Descendants("Response").Select(Function(x) New With { _
                                          .ip = x.Element("IP").Value, _
                                          .code = x.Element("CountryCode").Value, _
                                          .countryName = x.Element("CountryName").Value, _
                                          .regionCode = x.Element("RegionCode").Value, _
                                          .regionName = x.Element("RegionName").Value, _
                                          .city = x.Element("City").Value,
                                          .zip = x.Element("ZipCode").Value, _
                                          .timeZone = x.Element("TimeZone").Value, _
                                          .latitude = Double.Parse(x.Element("Latitude").Value), _
                                          .longitude = Double.Parse(x.Element("Longitude").Value), _
                                          .metroCode = x.Element("MetroCode").Value _
                                      }).FirstOrDefault()

    End Sub
```